# How to handle empty zip files with C# ZipFile

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a program in C# which unzip files with ZipFile. It is normally working but if the zip file is empty it fails.

The code:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, dirName);
```

Is there a way to detect if the zip file is empty and delete it? (I do not want to delete the file if it fails and it is not empty.)

Comment: What's "empty zip file" mean? Describe empty? It's either a file or it's not.

Comment: Catch the resulting exception? Verify it first by checking the length? 0 bytes is invalid, while a zipfile with no zipped files inside it will have some sort of minimum length (don't know what it would be).

Comment: Docs say that you will get an exception in that case, just handle it. [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: What do you mean by *** if the zip file is empty it fails***

Comment: With "empty zip file" I mean a zip file with no files and it is 0 bytes.

Comment: You can filter by `catch(ExceptionWhenIsEmtpy)` and do whatever you need to do when that happens..

Comment: An empty zip file should not be 0 bytes.

Comment: `new FileInfo(myFile).Length == 0` -> complain.

Comment: If using ’ZipArchive’, check whether the count of the ’Entries’ property is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dirName) && Directory.Exists(dirName))
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, dirName);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // file is empty (as we already checked for directory)
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }


    // OR

    if (new FileInfo(fileName).Length == 0)
    {
        // empty
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, dirName);
    }
}
```

[How to check if file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007716/5048820)

Comment: You could/should combine these two, not `// OR`

Comment: I only used the second one, because I do not want to render an exception. It works just fine in my case.